# Javamail strange behavior

Tags: java, junit, tomcat7, jakarta-mail

Javamail works correct in JUnit test and GlassFish 3.1.2, but not works in Tomcat 7.0.41: all "From" headers is NULL!
What am I doing wrong?
When i run JUnit test with code:

```
        @Test
        public void emailTest() {

            try {

                Properties properties = new Properties();
                properties.put("mail.pop3.host", EMAILUtil.POP3_HOST);
                properties.put("mail.pop3.disabletop", true);

                Store emailStore = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties).getStore(EMAILUtil.STORE_TYPE);
                emailStore.connect(EMAILUtil.USER, EMAILUtil.PASSWORD);

                Folder emailFolder = emailStore.getFolder(EMAILUtil.DEFAULT_FOLDER);
                emailFolder.open(Folder.READ_WRITE);
                Message[] messages = emailFolder.getMessages();

                System.out.println("Message count: " + messages.length);

                int errorCount = 0;

                for (int i = 0, n = messages.length; i < n; i++) {
                   System.out.println("Message: " + messages[i].toString());
                   System.out.println("From: " + messages[i].getFrom());
                }

                emailFolder.close(true);
                emailStore.close();

            } catch (MessagingException ex) {
                System.out.println("Readings mails Exception: " + ex.getMessage());
                ex.printStackTrace(System.err);
            }        

        }
```

I get the correct results (same with GlassFish3 results):

```
 Message count: 406
 Message: com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Message@167a
 From: [Ljavax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;@f9ead4
 Message: com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Message@72f580
 From: [Ljavax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;@153b61e
```

when i run this code at Tomcat7 I get the following results (all "From" headers is null):

```
 Message count: 406
 Message: com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Message@95acf2
 From: null
 Message: com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Message@a38f9f
 From: null
```

can anyone help with this issue?
JUnit version: 4.5
Javamail version: 1.4.4 (also i try with 1.5.5 with same result)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add properties.put("mail.debug", "true"); and compare the debug output in both cases.

Also, try changing Session.getDefaultInstance to Session.getInstance.

Comment: thanks, i found the solution: in appengine-api-1.0-sdk-1.2.1.jar and in javax.mail-1.4.4.jar found conflicted packages